# Reset local administrator account password remotly

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to run this code on domain environment machine to reset local administrator account remoly.

```
        Dim Context As PrincipalContext = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, "MachineNameOrIP")
        Dim oUser As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(Context, IdentityType.Name, "LocalAdminName")
        oUser.SetPassword("SomePassword")
        oUser.Save()
```

always exception occurs says 'Network path not found' however I'm in admin group of that remote machine.
This code works fine in Windows Server 2008 R2, and it breaks in Windows 7 or 8.1

Comment: Try running the application elevated (As Admin)

Comment: Sorry Matt, Running application as admin does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately according to this [Microsoft article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356158(v=vs.90).aspx) you can not reset remote machine local user password as there's no way connecting to it its users database 'SAM file'.
And above mentioned 'MachineNameOrIP' should point to the name of the server and port hosting the ApplicationDirectory instance to which we will connect to and not just a normal other pc name.